# Why is $BPP \nsubseteq NP?$

Tags: computational-complexity

I'm studying for an exam, and one of the practice questions is this:

Assume an polynomial probabilistic algorithm exists for an NPC decision problem $A$. For a yes-instance it gives the right answer 80% of the time and for a no-instance 70% of the time. Can we conclude that $NP \subseteq BPP$?

And the answer is:

False, this cannot be concluded based on the above, and in general it is not known whether $NP \subseteq BPP$.

I came to the conclusion it was true, and I (together with a peer) can't figure out what I did wrong:
$A \in BPP$ since we have this algorithm (confirmed by one of the other questions / answers).
Since $A \in NPC$, every problem $X \in NP$ can be reduced to $A$. Then, if we run this algorithm, it will have the correct answer at least 80% (or 70%) of the time. Thus, every problem in $NP$ can be solved this way, thus there is a probabilistic algorithm for all $X \in NP$, thus $NP \subseteq BPP$.

My reasoning is obviously incorrect, because the assumption is true (I know such an algorithm for 3SAT), but "the relation between $NP$ and $BPP$ is not known" - wikipedia

Comment: I don't know anything about this but I don't understand how an algorithm that has a 20% chance of being wrong can be used to  produce a solution.

Comment: 1) by running it multiple times, it is possible to get the chance arbitrarily close to the correct answer.
2) For some problems finding the solution is really hard, but verifying whether something is a solution can be done pretty quickly. So you could use a probabilistic algorithm to find a possible solution and then verify it with a deterministic algorithm.